# Unable to connect to mongoDB client using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a beginner in `mongoose` and `mongo DB`. When I am trying to connect to `mongoDB` using `mongoose` , running the `app.js file` with the help of node `app.js` the process is struck.

I am not getting any output. When I am checking the `database` then also the `database` is not created.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

This is my code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  age: Number
});

const People = mongoose.model("People",peopleSchema);

const people = new People({
  name : "Umang",
  age: 25
})

people.save();
```

Comment: did you check MongoDB status?  try sudo systemctl status mongod

Comment: Try this small change and check what is the issue.                              people.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});

Comment: @mehta-rohan it's still struck after writing the code and I am unable to see anything

Comment: is the output screen is blank? how do you running the code?

Comment: @UmangUpadhayay : Please check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438747/cant-add-object-to-mongodb-array-inside-a-document/59442513#59442513) Overthere you can use your `people.save()` instead of `Chats.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": id }, { $push: chatMessage }, { new: true }).lean(true)`

Comment: @mehta-rohan using command: node index.js

Comment: Umang your code works fine, it creates the db and the collection. Only you had better to use the catch block in `people.save()` like this `people.save().then(doc => console.log("Saved:", doc)).catch(err => console.log(err => console.log(err)));`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command in your command prompt

```
npm install express
```

Then add the following code snippet.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number
});

const People = mongoose.model("People", peopleSchema);

const people = new People({
    name: "Umang",
    age: 25
})

people.save();


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node server listening on port 3000');
})
```

I have tested it and it is working.
Make sure `MongoDb` is connected

Comment: Thanks @aman for the help and all of you guys. It's working fine now..